# Leak checks by Instruments

Tags: ios

When I use Intruments to check leak,I get follow snapshot.who can help me explain it ,thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instrument can not find the variable name that allocated the memory so that you are getting the [no ivar] message. And it may convert into dangling pointer

Comment: so,there are some methods to fix it ?

Comment: You need to review your code that what kind of variable you have defined e.g weak or strong which are real needed or not.

You can Analyze you code by long pressing run button in xcode and check if there are leaks for variable or not.